# android Sugar ORM select Query , Android

Tags: android, orm, sugarorm

I'm using [Sugar ORm](https://github.com/satyan/sugar) and need to use folloing query :

```
public void selectByfriendId(String fId , int lastMsgId){
   select from table where (senderId = fId or receiverId = fId) and 
                           ( show = "1" and msg_Id > lastMsgId)
}
```

And That5 Is My Method :

```
public List<Chat> selectById(String cId , String fId , int lastMsgId){
    Select showChats = Select.from(Chat.class)
            .where(Condition.prop("senderid").eq(fId) ,
            Condition.prop("show").eq("1") , Condition.prop("msg_Id").gt(lastMsgId))
            .or(Condition.prop("receiverid").eq(fId), Condition.prop("show").eq("1") , 
            Condition.prop("msg_Id").gt(lastMsgId));
    Log.v(G.Logs.DB , "MessagesStack DataBase.SelectById showChats.list().size : " + showChats.list().size());
    return  showChats.list();
}
```

And tried this One :

```
    List<Chat> array = Chat.find(Chat.class , "(senderid = ? OR receiverid = ?) AND (show = ? AND msg_Id > ?)", fId , fId , "1" , ""+lastMsgId);
```

but it shows me whole rows in table

Comment: That kind of select is supported with http://www.rushorm.com/ by using startGroup and endGroup to add the brackets.

Comment: lastMsgId changed wrongly out of method , thank you to help me

Comment: check the docs out for executing raw query http://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html